# How can I access the serializer in extra actions?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two classes and I want two merge `EventInvitationCreateView` into `EventInvitationViewSet`.
However, I am struggling to bring `perform_create` into `create_invitation` as I still need to access `serializer`. Do you have any input on how to achieve that?

```
class EventInvitationCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = InvitationSerializer
    permission_classes = [RetoolPermission]
    queryset = Invitation.objects.none()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        email = serializer.validated_data["email"]
        event = self.request.event
        invitation_exists = Invitation.objects.filter(
            email__iexact=email, event=event
        ).exists()

        if invitation_exists:
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        serializer.save(event=event)


class EventInvitationViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = [RetoolPermission]
    serializer_class = InvitationSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["email"]
    queryset = Invitation.objects.none()

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        return self.request.event.invitations.all()

    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"])
    def create_invitation(self, request, pk=None):
        [...perform_create]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't it the same serializer after all? It would be `InvitationSerializer` for both cases.

Comment: You're right. I read too fast. So what exactly are you trying to do? Put the create action at a different route?

Comment: No problem. I want to merge `EventInvitationCreateView` into `EventInvitationViewSet`. However in `EventInvitationCreateView` I use `perform_create` which I basically want to use inside `def create_invitation(self, request, pk=None):`.

Comment: Ok and what is the end goal. Cause the only difference is that an extra route `/create_invitation` is added for the create operation, which is not very restful. I would just put perform_create inside the viewset and be done with it, no need for an extra action route.

Comment: Ah you mean just moving `perform_create` down in `EventInvitationViewSet` will also work? Haven't tested that, but will do that now.

Comment: That seems to work as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the action is still a standard view's method, so you can use `self.get_serializer()`

for instance

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=["post"])
def create_invitation(self, request, pk=None):
    s = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    ....
```

If you need to use a "action specific serializer" you can specify the serializer class in the decorator

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=["post"], serializer_class=MyOtherSerializer)
def create_invitation(self, request, pk=None):
    s = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)  # <-- instance of MyOtherSerializer
    ....
```